Contents and Table of Contents
I'd like to create a table of contents at the beginning of my LaTeX document and put the table of contents at the end of my LaTeX document.
Is it possible?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\blindtext

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

\blindtext

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext
\end{document}


Simple answer: Yes, just put \tableofcontents at the end of your document. Or maybe I don't fully understand your question. Do you want to put the ToC twice?

I've already tried this but it doesn't work

what do you mean by doesn't work?  You never "create the table of contents at the beginning", it is written in stages at each \section, then it is printed wherever you put \tableofcontents. what error did you get?

The table of contents is a complete list of the parts and subparts of a document.
The summary is generally more succinct and does not necessarily include all the sub-sections. The summary provides a summary of the upcoming parts of the document and is thus located at the beginning of the document.
And I'd like to create a table of contents at the beginning of my LaTeX document and put the table of contents at the end of my LaTeX document.

what do you mean by "create" here? you can not create a table of contents at the start, you need to have processed all the sections to have the data. On a later run, once the data is in the aux file, you can print the table anywhere.

So, you want to put a ToC at the beginning that only shows the parts (or parts and chapters or sections, so just a partial ToC) of your document and another, complete ToC at the end of your document, right? You can try with the titletoc package, for example which allows to print partial ToCs at different positions of the document.

@JasperHabicht yes exactly

Glad @JasperHabicht managed to guess some meaning here, but there is nothing in your question that mentions a partial table of contents, you just say you want to print the table of contents at the end (and some statement about creation) even now you could edit the question to be more useful to future readers.

I have to second David's comment. It was not clear from your question at all that you want to typeset two different ToCs covering the same document at different places in your document. Maybe you can add a small clarification to your question in this regard.

If I understand your question (including the comments to it) correctly, you want to have a partial ToC at the beginning of your document that only shows the sections (for example) and another, exhaustinve ToC at the end. This can be achieved with the titletoc package easily:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{0}[1]{}

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\blindtext

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

\subsection{A Subsection}

\blindtext

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext

\printcontents{}{0}{}

\end{document}




You might want to format the ToCs and add some headers to them. Look at the manual of the titlesec package which also contains a description for the titletoc package for details.

The table of contents just appears wherever you place \tableofcontents

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }
\begin{document}

\maketitle



\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\blindtext

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

\blindtext

\section{Second Section}

\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\end{document}

